# How to prevent Simple HTML DOM plaintext from concatenating words together for sequential <div> elements

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm parsing a web page which contains the following excerpt:

```
<div>foo</div><div>bar</div>
```

With the following code:

```
$html = file_get_html("http://example.com");
$pt = $html->plaintext;
echo $pt;
```

`$pt` returns "foobar". What I want is "foo bar", i.e. add a blank space between words that are in separate elements.

There are other elements besides `<div>` where I'm seeing this behaviour, so the solution has to be generic across all element types that can contain viewable text.

Is there a way to either manipulate the `$html` object to add spaces between elements or have `plaintext` add spaces after each word it finds? I can deal with having a double space in the resulting `$pt`.

I tried `$html = str_replace ( "</" , " </" , $html );`, but the result is null, likely because I'm trying to edit an object, not a string, and then the object got mangled.

**Update**

Based on some feedback, I tried the following:

```
$webString = file_get_contents("http://example.com");
$webString = str_replace ( "</" , " </" , $webString );  // add a space before all <tag> closures.

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($webString);

$pt = $html->plaintext;
echo $pt;
```

This has the desired result, but I don't know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: yes @Dekel - I responded. Have you tried using your method, as it doesn't work for me.

Comment: If efficiency is really the goal, simple-html-dom should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have no way of determining which elements will generate a result for `plaintext`, if you read the complete page as a string, you can then do a `str_replace` to add in a space before each tag close character. (`</htmltag>`)

The other suggested answers in here depend on knowing what elements contain readable text, but this is not known ahead of time.

This seems to generate the desired effect:

```
$webString = file_get_contents("http://example.com");
$webString = str_replace ( "</" , " </" , $webString );  // add a space before all <tag> closures.

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($webString);

$pt = $html->plaintext;
echo $pt;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's getting concatenated when you use the plaintext method. The following should get you an array of the divs.

```
$html = file_get_html("http://example.com");
$pt = $html->find('div');
print_r($pt);
```

Comment: That might work if all of the text was in divs. What about `<div>` inside a `<div>` or an `<h4>` next to a `<div>`?

Comment: `find()` will retrieve things using any CSS selector string, sort of like jQuery. So for your examples you could `$html->find('div div')` or `$html->find('div + h4')`

Comment: You can also use classes and IDs

Comment: Since I'm parsing many pages, each written by different people / wordpress themes etc, I have no way of determining every combination of `<tag>` that could exist, thus the request for a generic solution.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could `$html->find('*')`, or you could use `file_get_contents` instead of `file_get_html` and just get one long string of HTML that you could parse.

Comment: I've got something working now using `file_get_contents` (see the updated question) but I don't know how robust or efficient it will be.

Comment: If you have no control over the contents of the sites you're scraping, that might be as good as it will get. Though, you might consider adding a newline character at the end of block level elements and applying the space to inline elements if you don't want one big block of text.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and i wanted to get plaintext with bold and I faced the contamination problem, to do this simply do this :
first, find all bold text and store them on an array
next, you grab the inner text of the element you want
finally, strip tags (another step that was only for me is replace all text from bolds array with **text from table here**)

```
$elements = $html->find('p');
foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
        $text = $element->innertext;
        $text = strip_tags($text);
        // one extra step for me only I replace bold texts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `file_get_contents` to get a string rather than an object of the HTML, you can use `preg_match_all` to get all div tags, then apply `strip_tags` to every matching tag using `array_walk` to leave you with the value.

Try this:

```
$str = file_get_contents("some_file_with_your_html.php");
// Assume the above returns something like the below
$str = "<div>sdsd</div><div id='some_id_1' attribute>test</div><div><div>inside</div></div><div><h1>header</h1></div><p>sdscdsds</p><div>another</div>";

// matches all div tags with any optional attributes and CSS declarations
$tagsFound = preg_match_all("|<div([^>]?)+>(.*)</div+>|U", $str, $matches);
if ((bool)$tagsFound !== false) {
    // Apply the anonymous function to each array value
    array_walk($matches[0], function (&$value, $index) {
        $value = strip_tags($value);
    });
}
```

This will leave you with an array of text within the HTML:

```
print ('<pre>');
print_r($matches[0]);
print ('</pre>');
```

```
Array
    (
        [0] => sdsd
        [1] => test
        [2] => inside
        [3] => header
        [4] => another
    )
```

You can then do an `implode` on the resulting array to get your words separated by a space, if you need to.

References:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php